# How can I debug expect_before behaviour

Tags: tcl, expect

I am relatively new to TCL / expect and mostly modifying existing code.
`expect_before` doesn't seem to do what I expect (which is fine) but I can't work out how to debug it.
I have used `-d` option and am now using

```
exp_internal -f "argh.log" 1
```

to create a log file, but it isn't helping me.

```
expect_before -info
```

seems useful, but I am not able to grab / display the output (I did say I was new to TCL)

Comment: exp_internal didn't help - because expect_before was being cancelled between my set-up and the expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function results can be grabbed in expect by the use of `set`

```
set my_expect_before [expect_before -info -all]
```

will grab the current configuration.

Using `exp_internal` is also useful to see how expressions are evaluated, and once you understand the output - it should be obvious when your expect_before has not been set up as expected.